# Knitting software for Android, AR, and connected knitting machines

Tags: android, augmented-reality

I was wondering whether there is a kind of software for Android that helps you learn how to knit (and make several patterns and make knitting designs, so that you may design a knitting, and, then, transfer the design wirelessly to a knitting machine that carries the knitting out for you).

I wonder whether there are even basic apps that teach you various knitting patterns by displaying drawings on screen (which you may then replicate using knitting tools).

Is there even why AR programs that will allow you to practice knitting via the AR interface (thus allowing you to knit virtual stuff)?

It works even be nice if there were some modeling software, like Adobe Illustrator or Blender or AutoCAD, but specifically for knitting, that allowed you to code a knitting pattern, choose to have it repeated and at what angle, and, once the design is complete, to send the design to the knitting machine to carry out as many garments of the design as needed.

Thanks.